# Proof regarding a subgroup of a cyclic group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I am practicing Abstract Algebra using course resources from when it was taught at my university last year. I am confused, in part (b) as to how $x^a=e$. Could someone explain this?

[image]

Comment: That is just the definition of $H$, isn't it?

Comment: But we are trying to show that $x\in H$, how did they use the definition of H?

Comment: No. For this direction you are assuming that $x\in H$ and you want to deduce that $x=(g^b)^m$ for some integer $m$.

Comment: I'm referring to the "conversely" part of (b), supposing $x\in\langle g^b \rangle$ and show $x\in H$. Bottom part

Comment: Sorry, I just saw the second sentence and assumed that that's what you were talking about... 
You have $x^a=(g^{bt})^a=(g^{ab})^t=e^t=e$. I don't actually understand the notation in the proof.

Comment: But why is that equal to $e$?

Comment: @MathDoer2320 $x^{a}=(g^{ab})^t=e^t=e$ because we are given that the order of $g$ is $ab$ (i.e. $g^{ab}=e$).

Comment: $e$ is the neutral element. Thus $e^t=e$... That is also the first sentence of part a

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use generic terms like "question" in the title. All posts on this site are questions – imagine how the main page would look and how inefficient it would be if everyone did that.

Comment: That is a very good point you bring up @jokiri. I'll refrain from doing that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a change in notation might help.

Here $$H=\{\xi\in G\mid \xi^a=e\}.$$

Let $x\in H$. Then, by definition, $x\in G$ such that $x^a=e$, since $x$ has to be one such $\xi\in H$.